# I could not launch Php files using Aptana Studio 3

Tags: wamp, aptana3

I recently  downloaded the Aptana Studio 3 and installed it on my computer..I also configure the webserver in aptana by navigating in window > preferences > webservers, and then i click new button i choose "external web server". then filled all fields ,

- Name:WampSerever
- Base URL://localhost
- C:\wamp\www
- Start Command: NET START wampapache
- stop Command:  NET STOP wampapache

After that, when i am going to test my php by clicking the green button above in the Aptana Studio select "Run firefox-Internal Server"...the firefox open but it displays blank page...

This is what is displayed in the URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:8020/TestAptana/Hello.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code is correct then try this. I use XAMMP as my server so I'm not sure if this will work with WAMMP.

Go to run configurations select Web Browser then choose which browser you want to use. Then in the main tab under **Server** find **"Use base URL"** and click on it. Enter `http://localhost/` and make sure that you check the **"Append project name"**.

Make sure that your index page's name is index.html or index.php if you are using php and try running it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, but one additional thing you need to is to set the path for PHP.exe.

Do this by going to Preferences/Aptana Studio/Editors/PHP/PHP Interpreter. Add and fill in blanks (browse) to php.exe.